# Django related classes in the same admin screen

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following class:

```
class Pedido(models.Model):

    idcliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, db_column='idCliente')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return Cliente.objects.get(id=idcliente).nome, Pedido.id
```

For each Pedido I have many itens, as the class shows:

```
class Item(models.Model):
   idpedido = models.ForeignKey('Pedido', db_column='idPedido') 
   idproduto = models.ForeignKey('Produto', db_column='idProduto')
   quantidade = models.SmallIntegerField()
   def __unicode__(self):
      return "%s Qtd: %s => %s" % (self.idproduto.nome, self.quantidade, self.idpedido)
```

In the admin area, I would like to enter the Items for each Pedido in the same screen. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use an [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects):

```
class ItemInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Item

class PedidoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ItemInline]
```